# Input a specific day or days to retrieve data

Tags: sql-server

I'm using Visual Studio 2008 and SQL Server 2008, I have 5 check boxes on my web form labelled Monday to Friday, in the database are two date fields (From and To) if I check Monday and submit I would like to retrieve data for where transactions took place on the Monday only.

If I check Monday and Friday I would like to see transactions that took place on a Monday and Friday only

Many thanks for your help

Comment: very good question.I will create enum where monday=1,tuesday=2,wdnesday=4,thursday=8,friday=16,sat=32,sunday=64.and keep one column for it in DB.now do bitwsie operation to save all slected value in new column and similarly to populate back checkboxes.
Just google little bit in google about enum bitwise operation.This is the best solution performance wise.

Answer (score 2):

you can use the function DATEPART to retrieve the weekday from the date to achieve your aim.

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms174420.aspx

Comment: If there are 100's of records in the database - Fields (From and To) and I wanted Monday transactions only would datepart still work

Comment: Yes! At your where clause you should put something like: datepart(dw,dateFrom) = 2 or datepart(dw,dateTO) = 2 //retrieve Mondays.

Comment: Whilst the answer is 100% accurate, it will not scale well if the table becomes large. Even if there's an index on the column, it'll be badly used as you're going to be querying on a function based upon the column. If you are going to be scaling this upwards then it may well behoove you to add this as a calculated persisted column and place an index on it. Nonetheless it's getting the up vote from me.

Comment: I have retrieved data for Monday and it works very well, slight issue tho

Comment: My dates don't run sequentially, if a transaction is weekly it will be saved as From Date '07/09/2015 and To Date '07/09/2015'  how can you retrieve Wednesday

Have tried DATEPART(dw, FromDate) = 2+2, it won't retrieve anything back

Comment: take a look at datepart at [https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms174420.aspx](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms174420.aspx) 
You will find there all the numbers for each week day.

At you designed view, your check boxes from monday to friday should send to the controller (I am assuming that you are using mvc pattern) a number from 2 to 6, and you controller should pass those values to the DAO as parameter to compose the query like: (ie. checked monday and wednesday)

`select * 
from YOURDB 
where datepart(dw, dateFrom) in (2,4)
 or datepart(dw, dateTo) in (2,4)`

Comment: See that `(2,4)` used in the example, will be dynamic. It will depend of the values checked at your views

Comment: Many thanks for your help, I designed a stored procedure to individualise the days to run sequentially using temporary tables and a where clause. It all works. 

I then build up C# code to build the query so I can pass in my parameters. Is there an easier way as opposed to using nested if statements to do the following

Comment: if Monday is checked and Tuesday is checked then my where clause will include an Or otherwise omit the Or and so on 

DatePart(dw,DateFrom) == 2 or DatePart(dw,DateFrom) == 3

Comment: I'm progressing slowly with this.....have come up with the following

        List<CheckBox> s = new List<CheckBox>();
        s.Add(chkMon);
        s.Add(chkTue);
        s.Add(chkWed);
        s.Add(chkThu);
        s.Add(chkFri);
        foreach (CheckBox c in s)
        {
            //c.Checked = true;
            if (c.Checked == true)
            {
                c.ID= c.ID + " " + c.ID;
            }
        }

I'm trying to concatenate my or statement

Comment: List<CheckBox> s = new List<CheckBox>();
        s.Add(chkMon);
        s.Add(chkTue);
        s.Add(chkWed);
        s.Add(chkThu);
        s.Add(chkFri);
        foreach (CheckBox c in s)
        {
            count = count + 1;
            if (c.Checked == true)
            {
                round = round + 1;
                WhereClause = "DATEPART(dw,FromDate) = " + count;
                if (round >= 2)
                {
                    WhereClause1 = WhereClause + " or DATEPART(dw,FromDate) = " + count;
                }
            }
        }
    }

How do you concatenate

Comment: created a test scenario (in Java) where you can play. I used your code as sample, of course, adapting to java. [http://rextester.com/OOHIH64181](http://rextester.com/OOHIH64181)